# SQL query select data between two date fields not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following values in my table

[image: DaTA WHICH ARE THERE]

```
Select * From TimeSheetLogs where InTimeStamp <= '1/22/2013'
```

when i execute the above query i get null value

but as you can see i have 3 data with datefield as 1/22/2013

Then what i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that is correct because

```
'1/22/2013 19:21' > '1/22/2013 00:00'
```

Comment: then what should i do to get the values of date 22 as well.

Comment: Select * From TimeSheetLogs where CAST(InTimeStamp as Date) <= '1/22/2013'

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment to @Zdravko's good answer, you just need to cast your date:

```
Select * From TimeSheetLogs where CAST(InTimeStamp as Date) <= '1/22/2013'
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to truncate your dates first to remove the time portion. Then convert both sides to date datatype. The string '1/22/2013' is a string, not a date. By looking at data your InTimeStamp is timestamp datatype. You cannot compare date or timestamp to character w/out converting the char-s to date. I'm not sure what Database are you using. This is how you'd convert in Oracle using to_date function .

```
SELECT in_date, compare_date
  FROM
 (-- This is your InTimeStamp on the fly
  SELECT trunc(to_timestamp('2013-01-22 16:21:19.273', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff')) in_date -- this is your InTimeStamp  
      , to_date('1/22/2013', 'mm/dd/yyyy') compare_date
   FROM dual
 )
 WHERE in_date <= compare_date
/

Now you can compare two dates below - this is the output of above query:

in_date     compare_date
----------  ------------
1/22/2013   1/22/2013
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * From TimeSheetLogs 
where InTimeStamp <= select convert(datetime,'1/22/2013',101)
```